# How prove this inequality with $x+y+z=2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y,z\ge 0$,and such $x+y+z=2$,show that
$$\sum\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\ge  \dfrac{2}{15}\sum\sqrt{\dfrac{2+47x}{2-x}}$$

I tried C-S,Holder but without success.$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\right)^2(\sum x(y^2+z^2))\ge (x+y+z)^3$$

Comment: is there also a cyclic sum on the left?

Comment: This inequality is reversed inequality to the known Vasc's expression!

Comment: can you give me a link please, Michael?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg,Hello,which  inequality? Thanks

Comment: @wightahtl  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner  $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{2+47x}{2-x}}\geq15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\geq\frac{2\sqrt2}{15\sqrt{x+y+z}}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{48x+y+z}{y+z}}.$$
Now, by Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}x^2(y^2+z^2)\geq(x+y+z)^3$$ and by C-S
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{48x+y+z}{y+z}}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{48x+y+z}{6x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}\frac{6x+y+z}{y+z}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$225(x+y+z)^4\geq16\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{48x+y+z}{6x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}\frac{6x+y+z}{y+z},$$
which is
$$\sum_{sym}(30x^9y+237x^8y^2-42x^7y^3-237x^6y^4+12x^5y^5)+$$
$$+xyz\sum_{sym}(365x^7+3918x^6y+2142x^5y^2+3484x^4y^3)+$$
$$+x^2y^2z^2\sum_{sym}(11019x^4+39786x^3y+17141x^2y^2+34785x^2yz)\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{sym}(30x^9y+237x^8y^2-42x^7y^3-237x^6y^4+12x^5y^5)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}xy(x^2-y^2)^2(10x^4+79x^3y+6x^2y^2+79xy^3+10y^4)\geq0.$$
Done!